# ErrorBarFunction styles

Tags: graphics, plotting

I am having trouble making sense of the help I have found for the ErrorBarFunction command. I am looking for basic instructions on how to change the width, style, and color of my error bars. Specifically what I need is black error bars for the y-axis data with no horizontal lines at the top or bottom - just black vertical dashes whose length indicates the uncertainty of that data point.

Any instructions using a sample ErrorListPlot would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this [Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26845/plotting-errorbars-with-a-different-style) for useful information.

Comment: [This is another related example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42482/error-bar-plot-no-bars-but-rather-point-size-determined-by-errors).  Please do not use tags that are not related to the question (`graphs-and-networks`, `number-representation`).